# what is use of Formal Protocol Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

We can create protocol object in source code but what is use of formal Protocol object?

```
Protocol *myObj = @protocol(protocolName);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it to check if an object conforms to a protocol.

```
[anotherObject conformsToProtocol:myObj];
```