# what does Protocol* x = @protocol(aProtocolName) do in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I found that I could do such things in objc:

```
Protocol* aProtocol = @protocol(NSObject);
```

but what is this technique used for?

Comment: To do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436257/objective-c-runtime-best-way-to-check-if-class-conforms-to-protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have, for example, a container that offers a service to check that all of its contents conform to a protocol.

```
Protocol *contentProtocol;

- (void)setContentProtocol:(Protocol *)proto;
```

Then the user of the container could call:

```
[container setContentProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];
```

And somewhere in the container the check could be made:

```
[[item class] conformsToProtocol:contentProtocol];
```

Comment: or just `[item conformsToProtocol:contentProtocol]`

Answer (score 0):

[what is use of Formal Protocol Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647836/what-is-use-of-formal-protocol-object)
You can use it to check if an object conforms to a protocol.

```
[anotherObject conformsToProtocol:aProtocol];
```